# when my barcode scanner scan a barcode my textbox1 will get System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: error message. can someone help me

Tags: vb.net

When my barcode scanner scans a barcode, in my textbox, I will get

> System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: error message.

I have tried many ways to solve the problem but still no success. Can someone pls help me take a look ? Thanks

Below is my code

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim dataIn As String
    'Dim userText As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        SerialPort.PortName = "COM1"
        SerialPort.BaudRate = CInt("9600")
        SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
        SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
        SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
        SerialPort.Open()
        SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 200

        If SerialPort.IsOpen Then
            ' TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived

        dataIn = SerialPort.ReadExisting
        dataIn = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox1.Text += SerialPort.ReadExisting().ToString()
        SetText(TextBox1.ToString())

    End Sub
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal text As String)

    Private Sub SetText(ByVal text As String)
        If Me.TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As SetTextCallback = New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {text})
        Else
            Me.TextBox1.Text = text.ToString
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you understand what that `SetText` method is for?  It's to set the `Text` of the `TextBox`.  So why would you call it immediately after setting the `Text` of the `TextBox`?  The whole point of calling that method is so that it gets done on the UI thread.

Comment: As for the issue, what exactly do you think `TextBox1.ToString()` is going to do?  Maybe you should find out.

Comment: @jmcilhinney what I understand on textbox1, to string is mt textbox1 data will be string.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  after i change my TextBox1.ToString() tobe SetText(TextBox1.Text) when i using barcode scaner scan the barcode i am fail to get the barcode information to mt textbox1 can you pls give me some information

Comment: This is what comes from writing code without understand what that code is supposed to do.  In your `DataReceived` event handler you need to do two things.  Firstly, you need to get the available input text from the `SerialPort`.  Secondly, you need to display that text in the `TextBox`.  The `SetText` method is what does the second step.  Maybe you should be passing that method the actual text you want to display.  Any code in that event handler that doesn't do either of those two things should not be there.

Comment: The line with `dataIn = TextBox1.Text` looks wrong.  Shouldn't that be `TextBox1.Text = dataIn` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set all those properties and use the methods without an instance of `SerialPort`.

I am not familiar with serial port code but I suspect that the `sender` in the `DataReceived` event is the serial port. So just Cast `sender` to `SerialPort`. Call the `ReadExisting` method which returns a string and assign it to the `.Text` property of the `TextBox`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sp As New SerialPort()
    sp.PortName = "COM1"
    sp.BaudRate = CInt("9600")
    sp.Parity = Parity.None
    sp.StopBits = StopBits.One
    sp.Handshake = Handshake.None
    sp.Open()
    sp.ReadTimeout = 200
End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived
    TextBox1.Text += DirectCast(sender, SerialPort).ReadExisting
End Sub
```

Somewhere you need to dispose the port also.

Answer (score 0):

With the Bar Code Scanners I have used, there's been no need to monitor the serial port as the drivers handle that.  Normally the scanner simply reads and decoded the bar code and presents it as text to UI as if typed by the user.  However, assuming you serial port code is correct, try this (this is a copy of code I've used that also works for setting Text on a Combobox too, so you'll need to delete that. I left it in in case it was helpful with other controls you might be using):

```
Private Sub SerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived
    Dim ScannedText As String = DirectCast(sender, SerialPort).ReadExisting
    SetText(TextBox1, ScannedText)
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub SetTextDelegate(ByVal obj As Object, NewText As String)

Private Sub SetTextSub(ByVal obj As Object, NewText As String)
    Select Case obj.GetType.Name
        Case "ComboBox"
            CType(obj, ComboBox).Text = NewText
        Case Else
            CType(obj, TextBox).Text = NewText
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub SetText(ByVal obj As Object, NewText As String)
    Dim del As SetTextDelegate
    del = AddressOf SetTextSub
    Dim parArray() As Object = {obj, NewText}

    Select Case obj.GetType.Name
        Case "ComboBox"
            If CType(obj, ComboBox).InvokeRequired Then
                CType(obj, ComboBox).Invoke(del, parArray)
            Else
                SetTextSub(obj, NewText)
            End If
        Case Else
            If CType(obj, TextBox).InvokeRequired Then
                CType(obj, TextBox).Invoke(del, parArray)
            Else
                SetTextSub(obj, NewText)
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```